# Using a polygon as a marker with leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps, overlay, polygon

I currently have a map for a game with item locations, i'm wanting to add animals to the side bar/legend but as a polygon instead of a marker, i get how to draw a polygon but i cannot figure out how to make it only show when selected from the legend (or even how to add one to the legend). Sorry for this very basic question.

I'm really very new to this, I only started learning about leaflet to make a map for a game, so i'm not really sure how to explain what i've done.. so i'll try my best:

I have a list of markers like:
    `var marker_combulbrsh2 = L.marker([-1474, 2661.5])
.bindPopup('Common Bullbrush');`

and then i have the layer groups that have lines this like:
    `var lg_combulbrsh = L.layerGroup([
marker_combulbrsh1, marker_combulbrsh2
]);`

and then an overlay list with the layer groups like:
    `"<i>Common Bullbrush" : lg_combulbrsh,`

and then i have them display on the map with:
    `L.control.layers(null, overlays, {collapsed:true, position: 'topleft'}).addTo(map);`

I am wanting to add a series of polygons that are selectable from the side panel/legend in the same way that the above L.marker is, so that I don't have to add individual locations that are close together for adding animal locations to the map.

```
`var polygonPoints = [
    [-2263, 432],
    [-2361, 435],
    [-2337, 674],
    [-2263, 432]];
  var poly = L.polygon(polygonPoints).addTo(map);`
```

The code above draws the polygon i want to draw, but it's permanently there and I haven't been able to figure out how to make it a selectable item like the `L.markers` are. I figure i have to add the polygon as a marker some how and then have that marker added to the layer group and create an entry for them on the overlay list and then have them display through `L.control.layers` - I just cannot wrap my head around how though.

again, sorry for this very basic question and thank you to anyone who reads. if you are able to help with this and would like credit added to the website with a link to your work or social media or something i'm more than happy to do so.

Comment: I too am interested in the answer to this question, as i am looking to do similar behaviours in my app.